# Math Olympiad 2020 (BdMO-Secondary-National)

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Let $x_1, x_2,\ldots$ be real numbers so that for all $n > 0,$
$$x_{n+3} = x_{n+2} - 2x_{n+1} + x_n. $$
Suppose $x_1 = x_3 = 1$ and you're given that $x_{98} = x_{99}$.

Find the sum $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_{100}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs.  For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this image for solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAb7v.jpg)

Could not write this in MathJax, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

Given that

$$
x_{n+3} = x_{n+2} - 2x_{n+1} + x_n,
$$

one can rewrite this as

$$
x_{n+3} - x_{n+2} =  - 2x_{n+1} + x_n \Leftrightarrow
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
x_{4} - x_{3} &=  - 2x_{2} + x_1 \\
x_{5} - x_{4} &=  - 2x_{3} + x_2 \\
x_{6} - x_{5} &=  - 2x_{4} + x_3 \\
\ldots \ldots \ldots &\ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \\
x_{98} - x_{97}  &=  - 2x_{96} + x_{95} \\
x_{99} - x_{98}  &=  - 2x_{97} + x_{96} \\
x_{100} - x_{99} &=  - 2x_{98} + x_{97} 
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, let us add all these equalities:

$$
x_4-x_3 + x_5-x_4 + x_6-x_5 + \ldots x_{98}-x_{97} + x_{99}-x_{98} + x_{100}-x_{99} = -2\sum_{n = 2}^{98}x_n + \sum_{n = 1}^{97}x_n.
$$

In the left-hand side, many terms are canceled out:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&-x_3 + x_{100} = -2\sum_{n = 2}^{97}x_n - 2x_{98} + x_1 + \sum_{n = 2}^{97}x_n \Leftrightarrow \\ 
&-x_3 + x_{100} = -\sum_{n = 2}^{97}x_n - 2x_{98} + x_1 \Leftrightarrow \\ 
&-x_3 + \sum_{n = 2}^{97}x_n + 2x_{98} + x_{100} = x_1 \Leftrightarrow \\
&x_1 + \sum_{n = 2}^{97}x_n + 2x_{98} + x_{100} = 2x_1 + x_3 \Leftrightarrow  \\
&\left|
\begin{array}{l}
\text{since }x_{98} = x_{99}, \text{ then }2x_{98} = x_{98} + x_{99} \\
\text{since }x_{1} = x_{3} = 1, \text{ then }2x_{1} + x_{3} = 3
\end{array}
\right| \Leftrightarrow  \\
&\sum_{n = 1}^{100}x_n = 3.
\end{aligned}
$$